# Problemas ao centralizar um conteúdo ao trabalhar com flexbox no CSS

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Estou tentando aprender CSS e me deparei com flexbox e não estou conseguindo trabalhar com os tutoriais que vejo na internet.

O objetivo era centralizar, eixo X e Y, 3 quadrados na pagina, mas só consegui centralizar no eixo X.

Código:

```css
.box{
        background-color: #AF1DC7;
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px; 
        margin: 25px;
        border-radius: 10px;
    }
    .elements-container{
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;
    }
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="prob01_formulario.css">
        <title>Desafio 1</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="elements-container">
            <div class="box"></div>
            <div class="box"></div>
            <div class="box"></div>
        </div>      
    </body> 
    </html>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Está centralizado na vertical sim, o que acontece é que seu *containe flex* não tem altura suficiente para vc perceber o conteúdo centralizado verticalmente nele

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Se vc declarar um `height` para ele vc vai ver que etá no centro

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="prob01_formulario.css">
<title>Desafio 1</title>
<style>
  .box {
    background-color: #AF1DC7;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 25px;
    border-radius: 10px;
  }

  .elements-container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;

    height: 100vh;
    border: 1px solid black;
  }
</style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="elements-container">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 3):

Os elementos estão centralizados tanto no eixo X quanto eixo Y do *flex container*.

Veja, quando você faz:

> ```
> .elements-container {
>   display: flex;
>   align-items: center;
>   justify-content: center;
>   flex-direction: column;
> }
> ```

Você está "dizendo" que o elemento de seletor `.elements-container` é o *flex container* com a propriedade `display: flex`. Através da propriedade `justify-content: center`, você centraliza o elemento no eixo Y. E através da propriedade `align-items: center`, você os centraliza no eixo X.

<sup>Só para constar que, por padrão, `justify-content` relaciona-se ao eixo X e `align-items`, ao Y. No entanto, a propriedade `flex-direction: column` "inverte" esse comportamento.</sup>

Então por que os elementos não estão sendo centralizados no eixo Y?

Eles estão — só quem em relação ao *flex container*. O problema é que, atualmente, o *flex container* pode não ocupar toda a altura do monitor. Veja:

[image: TODO]

Repare que o *flex container* não está ocupando todo o tamanho vertical da tela. Desse modo, embora os itens estejam, sim, centralizados horizontalmente e verticalmente, eles não conseguem ocupar todo o tamanho vertical.

Uma forma de se resolver isso é garantir que o *flex container* possua, no mínimo, 100% do tamanho da tela. Para isso, pode-se fazer:

```
.elements-container {
  min-height: 100vh;
}
```

Definimos que o tamanho mínimo do *flex container* é 100% do tamanho da *viewport*. Só para constar que `vh` é uma unidade relativa de medida do CSS, de modo que `1vh` sempre corresponderá a 1% da altura da tela do usuário.

Juntando tudo:

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.box{
        background-color: #AF1DC7;
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px; 
        margin: 25px;
        border-radius: 10px;
    }
    .elements-container{
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;
        min-height: 100vh;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="prob01_formulario.css">
        <title>Desafio 1</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="elements-container">
            <div class="box"></div>
            <div class="box"></div>
            <div class="box"></div>
        </div>      
    </body> 
    </html>
```

Note que eu também adicionei esta regra:

```
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

Para impedir que o *margin* e *padding* padrão desses elementos atrapalhe a definição de tamanho que foi feita.

Comment: Haha a mesma resposta, 30 segundos mais rápido que eu =)

Comment: @hugocsl, pois é! :D

Comment: @hugocsl queria conseguir marcar as duas como solução :D

Answer (score 0):

Utilizando o `Grid` fica mais flexível (aliás, desta forma já é flexível) você ajustar os items de acordo com o container, desta forma:

```css
body, html {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  width: 100%; /* ocupar 100% da largura da página*/
  height:100%; /* ocupar 100% da altura da página */
}
.elements-container{
  display: grid;
  width: 100vw; /* baseado na largura do body/html */
  height: 100vh; /* baseado na altura do body/html */
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr; /* divido em 3 linhas (frações) */
  justify-content: center; 
  align-items: center;
}

.elements-container > .box{
  background-color: #AF1DC7;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px; 
  margin: 25px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="prob01_formulario.css">
        <title>Desafio 1</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="elements-container">
            <div class="box"></div>
            <div class="box"></div>
            <div class="box"></div>
        </div>      
    </body> 
    </html>
```

Espero que tenha o ajudado!