# Centralização bootstrap vertical não funciona

Tags: php, jquery, html5, css3, twitter-bootstrap

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Como faço para centralizar verticalmente essa parte rosa no centro do amarelo? Usei align-items-center e não funciona.
E também necessito centralizar verticalmente e horizontalmente o texto.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        
        <head>

            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
            <link rel='stylesheet' href='estilo.css' />
            <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width' />
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            
            

        </head>

        
        <body>
            <div class='container-fluid'>
                <div class='row'>
                    <div class='col-12 a'>
                        <div class='row justify-content-center'>
                            <div class='col-8 b'>
                                <div class='row justify-content-around align-items-center'>
                                    <div class='col-2 c'>
                                        Homepage
                                    </div>
                                    <div class='col-2 c'>
                                        About Us
                                    </div>
                                    <div class='col-2 c'>
                                        Services
                                    </div>
                                    <div class='col-2 c'>
                                        Contact
                                    </div>
                                    <div class='col-2 c'>
                                        External
                                    </div>
                                </div>


                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js" integrity="sha256-H+K7U5CnXl1h5ywQfKtSj8PCmoN9aaq30gDh27Xc0jk=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script type='text/javascript' src='script.js'></script>
        </body>
            


        

    </html>
```

.a {

```
        background-color: gray;
        height: 50px;
    }
    .b {
        background-color: yellow;
        height: 50px;
    }
    .c {
        background-color: pink;
        height: 35px;
    
    }
```

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [Problemas ao centralizar um conteúdo ao trabalhar com flexbox no CSS](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/494510/problemas-ao-centralizar-um-conte%c3%bado-ao-trabalhar-com-flexbox-no-css)

Comment: É que queria saber se tem solução via bootstrap, e nessa pergunta é via flexbox

Comment: Para prosseguir com a dúvida no acervo do site é importante [edit] e trocar o código atual por um [mcve] do problema, o que além de agilizar para o entendimento da parte a que se refere e obter uma solução para o problema específico, faz com que o post também sirva de referência para outras pessoas (que é a finalidade do site). Para entender que tipo de pergunta serve para o site e minimizar fechamentos e negativações vale a pena ler [O que é o Stack Overflow](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7256/70) e o [Guia de sobrevivência do site](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8089/70).

Comment: Uai, mas o código postado é totalmente um [mcve].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Coloca um `h-100` na `row` para que ela tenha a mesma altura da div onde ela está, já que você definiu ela com altura de `50px` na classe `.b`:

```
<div class='row justify-content-around align-items-center h-100'>
                                                            ↑
```

Assim a classe `align-items-center` irá surtir efeito.

E para centralizar verticalmente/horizontalmente o texto, use flexbox também nas divs com a classe `.c`:

```
.c {
   background-color: pink;
   height: 35px;
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
   justify-content: center;
}
```

**Exemplo:**

```css
.a {
   background-color: gray;
   height: 50px;
}
.b {
   background-color: yellow;
   height: 50px;
}
.c {
   background-color: pink;
   height: 35px;
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
   justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class='container-fluid'>
    <div class='row'>
        <div class='col-12 a'>
            <div class='row justify-content-center'>
                <div class='col-8 b'>
                    <div class='row justify-content-around align-items-center h-100'>
                        <div class='col-2 c'>
                            Homepage
                        </div>
                        <div class='col-2 c'>
                            About&nbsp;Us
                        </div>
                        <div class='col-2 c'>
                            Services
                        </div>
                        <div class='col-2 c'>
                            Contact
                        </div>
                        <div class='col-2 c'>
                            External
                        </div>
                    </div>


                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js" integrity="sha256-H+K7U5CnXl1h5ywQfKtSj8PCmoN9aaq30gDh27Xc0jk=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```